# Return a list of files/filenames in order to find where a pattern of filenames breaks

Tags: command-line, terminal

I have a folder containing hundreds of files with filenames such as `month-day-time.txt` 
They follow a pattern of 1 file for every 10th minute of the hour, as in the example (here the minutes differentiate the files):

```
06-03-01h10.txt

06-03-01h20.txt

06-03-01h30.txt
```

What Terminal command and syntax should I use to get a list of filenames (or files) that are missing thus breaking the filename pattern?

Example: if `06-03-01h40.txt` doesn't exist, I'd like it to appear in the returned list of filenames or files.

Comment: My preference would be to pipe ls to a file, and use regex to search the file.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Even then, a regex to search for a numeric pattern that involves arithmetic isn't normal regex functionality

Comment: AT Ramhound what do you expect him to try. what would you try (aside from  coding a program to do it  -  which he might not be able to do) ? (And even then, it's a complex problem, just saying 'i tried a for loop' won't he that helpful and at that level is more Stackoverflow).  it's not like there are obvious things to just try.

Comment: In a programming language, I would generate the list of expected filenames in a loop, check if the file exists, and list any missing, though i do not know how to do so from terminal.

Comment: similar to Moishe Pippik, i'd use some programming language or other, but i'd do a stage 1, of  scanning through hte list of filesnames of existing files, and then see if the filename before and after it matcbes the pattern, if it does then mark that filename with the text "yeah" to the right of it.  otherwise mark "nope" to the right of it.  Then examine the output and think about adjusting stage 1 or think about your stage 2. along the lines of outputting all the files marked "yeah" up to one marked "nope".

Comment: if you know any programming language then consider trying it in that but then it's a stackoverflow question

Comment: Thank you All. @ barlop differentiating between ''yeah'' and ''nope'' files is very handy, I will work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using {00..05} in bash, tries the command with 00 then 01, 02 etc.

```
ls {01..12}-{01..31}-{01..24}h{00,10,20,30,40,50}.txt 1>/dev/null
```

Will give you errors only for the files that do not exist, edit the code to exclude months you don't have etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pipe it to a file, load it into Excel, generate a list of *expected* file names in the next column then use a VLOOKUP to see which ones in the expected list are not in the actual list.

Comment: Though this isn't a solution using Terminal, thinking about it I believe the list of 'expected' filenames wouldn't work after the 1st filename that breaks the pattern occurs. Then the following filenames wouldn't be a match to the column of 'expected' filenames.

Comment: @Chris No, it doesn't work that way. It's not expecting a 1-1 match. VLOOKUP can be used to just say whether the value EXISTS in the other list - so you'd end-up with a list of non-matching entries. But if you are dead-set on using terminal then I agree this answer is useless.